# Swift - NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: swift, firebase, nsarray

I'm getting data from a firebase node. But inside each node, has a child node (called productList) 
[See picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEkOI.png).

This snippet is where i am filling currentStores array from firebase.

```
let storesRef : DatabaseReference = dbRef.child("Services")

        storesRef.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: {(DataSnapshot) in

            if (DataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]) != nil {
                let dictionary = DataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                let store = Stores(storeName: dictionary?["name"] as! String,
                                   id: dictionary?["id"] as! String,
                                   type: dictionary?["type"] as! Int,
                                   averageScore: dictionary?["averageScore"] as! Float,
                                   avatarUrl: dictionary?["avatarUrl"] as! String,
                                   waitingTimeMin: dictionary?["waitingTimeMin"] as! Int,
                                   waitingTimeMax: dictionary?["waitingTimeMax"] as! Int,
                                   isService: dictionary?["service"] as! Bool,
                                   products: dictionary?["productList"] as! [Product])

                self.currentStores.append(store)
                self.hideLoading()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.mainTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
```

This is the constructor for Stores:

```
 var products = [Product]()

init(storeName: String, id: String, type: Int, averageScore: Float, avatarUrl: String, waitingTimeMin: Int, waitingTimeMax: Int, isService: Bool, products: [Product] = [Product]() ) {
        self.storeName = storeName
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.averageScore = averageScore
        self.avatarUrl = avatarUrl
        self.waitingTimeMin = waitingTimeMin
        self.waitingTimeMax = waitingTimeMax
        self.isService = isService
        self.products = products
    }
```

And then, when I fill the cell data from the store.productList, I get the error:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellReuse = "productCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuse, for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell

        //// THIS LINE: (NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type)
       cell.productNameLabel.text = store.products[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for Product class or struct?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 class Product {
    
    var name: String
    var price: Float
    var storeName: String
    
    init?(name: String, price: Float, storeName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.storeName = storeName
        print(name)
    }
}

Comment: Please add print(store.products[indexPath.row]) before cell.productNameLabel.text = store.products[indexPath.row] and see what is the output?

Comment: Same error: fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element

Comment: Please remove .name from end and then print and see what is the result?

Comment: I just did: print(store.products[indexPath.row]) and it gave that error ):

Comment: Ok good, please print(store) and see if it contains products array

Comment: It does. Check this image I uploaded: https://imgur.com/a/DK9Wt

Comment: Can you show me the code where you declare currentStores array?

Comment: here: https://imgur.com/a/QCA9m

Comment: Ok , can you check by adding this code in cellForRowAt method,  let products = store.products as? [Product]
    let firstProduct = products?[0]
    print(firstProduct), see what is printed on console and please remove or comment other code from cellForRow method where you access stores array

Comment: @3stud1ant3 look: https://imgur.com/a/fewZU

Comment: is your problem solved?